# How to change the secretKey in Dexie-Encrypted?

Tags: encryption, indexeddb, dexie

I've been looking for an example about how to modify the secretKey of a IndexedDB that is protected by Dexie-Encrypted.
So far I've read that if I wanna change the key, the version of the DB should be increase, but I can't really understand how to do it.
I'm new with the Dexie, so if anyone can help me, I would apreciate it

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I'm struggling with it too.